# Java/Gradle: How can I access gradle project properties from Java code

Tags: java, gradle

I have a Java code that produces some files under build directory. But I want it to respect buildDir parameter of Gradle.

When I set the buildDir parameter of Gradle from gradle.properties file or command line using -PbuildDir, I need to update "build" string in following Java according to the parameter.

```
 private List<String> getX() {
    List<String> AList = new ArrayList<>();
    AList.add("build/dir1/");
    AList.add("build/dir2/");
    return AList;
}
```

How is it possible?

----- UPDATE -----

Above code is a part of a library. This library is used by a gradle project later. I want to pass gradle parameters to the library.

Answer (score 1):

Is this java code a gradle task? If yes then it would be

```
private List<String> getX() {
    String buildDir = getProject().getBuildDir().getAbsolutePath();
    return Arrays.asList(
        buildDir + "/dir1", 
        buildDir + "/dir2"
    );
}
```

But if you wanted to do it "the Gradle way" you'd probably do it as:

```
public FileCollection getX() {
    String buildDir = getProject().getBuildDir().getAbsolutePath();
    return getProject().files(
        buildDir + "/dir1", 
        buildDir + "/dir2"
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated the question because I forgot something to write. Sorry about that. Above code is a part of a library. This library is used by a gradle project later. I want to pass gradle parameters to the library.